# Django Rest Framework - Displaying the User's Profile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My **users/models.py** file looks as below.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_courier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Profile(models.Model):
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My current **users/serializers.py** looks like below.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

My **users/api.py** looks like below.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

My **users/urls.py** has the below:

```
router.register('api/users', UserViewSet, 'users')
```

My current setup works well with the UserViewSet. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ displays all the users and http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/ displays the user according to the ID.

My question is, How can I load up the user profile when I goto the below the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/profile

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new serializer for **`Profile`** model

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"
```

then create a new view class for the **`Profile`**.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class ProfileAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=kwargs['user_id'])
        profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(user.profile)
        return Response(profile_serializer.data)
```

Then, wire up the view in **`urls.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your other url configs
    path('api/users/<user_id>/profile/', ProfileAPI.as_view())
]
```

---

### Update-1

Implementation using **`ViewSet`** class

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class ProfileAPI(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=kwargs['user_id'])
        profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(user.profile)
        return Response(profile_serializer.data)
```

---

### Update-2

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class ProfileAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['user_id'])
```

and in your `urls.py` register the viewset as

```
router.register('api/users/(?P<user_id>\d+)/profile', ProfileAPI, base_name='profile_api')
```

Comment: Thank JPG. This works. Is there a way that I can use rest_framework's viewsets to implement this rather than using the APIView?

Comment: `APIView` also belongs to ***DRF*** and I think *viewsets* classes are not required here since you are only dealing with the ***HTTP GET*** request

Comment: @NadunPerera Anyway, I've updated my answer. Hope it helps. and don't forget to mark and vote the answer :)

Comment: How would you register the URL for the viewset above in the urls.py?

Comment: you don't need to register it....as I said, it's only dealing with ***`HTTP GET`*** request

Comment: What if I want to add a complete ViewSet (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) for the Profile model? I would like to maintain the url structure /user/1/profile for GET, /user/1/profile/ for POST and so on...

Comment: You have to do the same things as you did for the **`User`** model and it's components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192608/discussion-between-nadun-perera-and-jpg).

Answer (score 0):

i have used **AbstractUser ** and **custom user manager **
i have used ViewSets.ViewSet along with Model Serializers

#urls.py file#

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import ProfileViewSet, LoginViewSet, RegisterViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'register', RegisterViewSet, basename='register')
router.register(r'login', LoginViewSet, basename='login')
router.register(r'profile', ProfileViewSet, basename='profile')

urlpatterns = [
path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

#views.py file#

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from .models import user_reg
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer


class ProfileViewSet(ViewSet):

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):    #partially update the profile

        try:
            user_detail = user_reg.objects.get(pk=pk)
           
            serializer = RegisterSerializer(user_detail,data=request.data, partial=True)

            if not serializer.is_valid():
                return Response({'data':'internal server error','message':'error aa gyi'},500)

            serializer.save()

        except Exception as e:

            return Response('some exception occured' + str(e))

        return Response('record Updated successfully')

    def retrieve(self,request, pk=None):    #get or retrieve the profile from database

        queryset = user_reg.objects.get(pk=pk)
    
        serializer_class = RegisterSerializer(queryset)
    
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

#serializer.py file#

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import user_reg

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = user_reg
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email')  #custom fields i made 
                                                                 u can change this
```

#models.py#

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager



class user_reg(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length= 8,blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='user'
```